# Debug variadic arguments

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, variadic-templates, clang-cl

I'm currently debugging an issue in our build where in variadic arguments, the number of arguments ain't as expected.

Currently my code looks similar to:

```
class CustomException : public BaseException
{
public:
    template<typename ...T>
    CustomException(T &&...args) : BaseException(std::forward<T>(args)...)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(T) == 2);
    }
};
throw CustomException{size_t{}, size_t{}};
```

Based on this code, one would expect 2 arguments are being passed to the Ctor.

Surprisingly, this code does as expected with MSVC and fails on the static_assert with Clang.

Does any of you know a trick to force clang to reveal what it assumes the variadic argument pack is?

**Edit** Problem is related to copy construction that is required to throw, very specific to Clang-Cl

Comment: Maybe [__PRETTY_FUNCTION__  can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338804/1708801)

Comment: one of these static asserts is guaranteed to fail so this code should not compile

Comment: [no repro](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pJawjxyFSZwTjj3G), code fails only on one static assert with clang

Comment: [still no repro](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PdCLh5qmk4LDi1WL), throw does not change anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [static\_assert dependent on non-type template parameter (different behavior on gcc and clang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078818/static-assert-dependent-on-non-type-template-parameter-different-behavior-on-gc)

Comment: This is technically UB, so clang can do whatever it wants. If you want to print something, you could `[[deprecated]] template<typename...> struct print {};`

Comment: Well, the answer seems to spot a bug, but in my defense the question _is_ UB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179244/discussion-between-jvapen-and-passer-by).

Comment: `template<typename ...T> CustomException(T &&...args)` -- that is code smell.  Do not have over greedy ctors.  `CustomException()` and `template<class T0, class...Ts, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T0>, CustomExceptiom>{}, bool> =true>(T0&&, Ts&&...)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem on hand seems to be a compiler bug, logged as https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38801

The full reproduction:

### test.cpp

```
struct A
{
   template<typename ... T>
   A(T &&...t)
   {
      static_assert(sizeof...(T) == 2);
   }

   A(const A &) = default;
   //A(A &) = default;
   A(A &&) = default;
   A &operator=(const A &) = default;
   A &operator=(A &&) = default;
};


int main(int, char **)
{
   throw A{size_t{}, size_t{}};
   return 0;
}
```

### run.bat

```
clang-cl.exe -fms-compatibility-version=19.11 /DBOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H -w -Wno-unused-command-line-argument /Zc:inline /nologo /c /GR /EHsc /fp:precise /FS /std:c++17 /diagnostics:caret /O2 /I. /MDd /Zc:forScope /bigobj /Zc:wchar_t test.cpp
```

### error

```
test.cpp(7,7):  error: static_assert failed
      static_assert(sizeof...(T) == 2);
      ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp(20,10):  note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'A::A<A &>' requested here
   throw A{size_t{}, size_t{}};
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: At least it seems to be fixed on the clang trunk: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v8gXQ5

Comment: @N00byEdge: Compiler explorer doesn't contain clang-cl as driver

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was clang-cl related. Nevermind.

Comment: I am uncertain if this is a bug; compilers maybe free to copy exceptions, and free not to.  If they copy (from a non-const lvalue) your code generates this error.  The bug may be in your over greedy ctor.