# How to assert that a constexpr if else clause never happen?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to raise a compile time error when non of the constexpr if conditions is true eg:

```
if constexpr(condition1){
    ...
} else if constexpr (condition2) {
   ....
} else if constexpr (condition3) {
  ....
} else {
    // I want the else clause never taken. But I heard the code below is not allowed
    static_assert(false);
}

// I'd rather not repeat the conditions again like this:
static_assert(condition1 || condition2 || condition3);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With C++23 the answer to this question changes. With the paper [P2593: Allowing static_assert(false)](https://wg21.link/P2593) which was accepted at [2023-02 Issaquah meeting](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1251). We are now allowed to use the idiom the OP wants to use.

We can see form the [accepted wording](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2518.html) that [dcl.pre p10](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#10) was modified so that `static_assert` has no effect in *template definition context* and that [temp.res p6](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-6) was modified so that it is no longer *ill-formed no diagnostic required* if a `static_assert` fails for all specializations.

It also added the following example:

```cpp
template <class T>
  void f(T t) {
    if constexpr (sizeof(T) == sizeof(int)) {
      use(t);
    } else {
      static_assert(false, "must be int-sized");
    }
  }
  
  void g(char c) {
    f(0); // OK
    f(c); // error: must be int-sized
  }
```

Answer (score 53):

You have to make the discarded statement dependent of the template parameters

```
template <class...> constexpr std::false_type always_false{};

if constexpr(condition1){
    ...
} else if constexpr (condition2) {
   ....
} else if constexpr (condition3) {
  ....
} else {       
    static_assert(always_false<T>);
}
```

This is so because

> **[[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1)** - The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if
>
> no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a `constexpr if` statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or ...

Comment: Why exactly is the condition you quoted no longer met if it depends on the template parameter? To my understanding it still holds that "no valid specialization can be generated".

Comment: Seeing stuff like that makes me think at some point in time we should have just kept to growing corn or something.

Comment: @AvivCohn I know what you mean. Or maybe move further and end up with a safer language? Some think it's Rust... Either way, I hope there will be one.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081493/5452773) claims that it's indeed *not* dependant on the template parameters, because it "does not differ from one instantiation to another", which would mean that cppreference is wrong.

Comment: @philipp2100 It's not even about safe vs. unsafe. It's just about a sane solution we can have a good time using. C++ has some beautiful parts, but others are just like... what were they thinking?

Comment: I also just stumbled over the "and the template is not instantiated" part of the quote. It seems that since the template *is* instantiated, the quote doesn't apply here at all. I couldn't find the wording on this in N4606 either, though. It would be great if someone could shed some light on all of this or ask a new question and link it here. Maybe I'll do it.

Comment: @philipp2100 - variable templates can be explicitly specialized. So a specialization *is possible* where the variable is in fact true. It's a slippery slope, and some don't like it, but it does circumvent the "always ill formed" nature of the condition.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I think you're right about that point. The answer I linked to that says "does not differ" refers to a different case where it's indeed never possible that they differ.

Comment: Because of the limitation "and the template is not instantiated", this paragraph indeed may not apply here but the next but one cited in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078818/static-assert-dependent-on-non-type-template-parameter-different-behavior-on-gc/30081493#30081493).

Comment: @philipp2100 - "The next one" mentions lack of dependence on the template parameter as a condition. The construct here is by definition, a dependent value.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes, I agree with that (if you refer to the construct in this answer, not the question).
I just wanted to clarify that IMO it's usually the third bullet point of [temp.res]/8 (`a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due
to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter`) that makes the dependence necessary, not the first one quoted in this answer (unless the template is indeed not instantiated).

Answer (score 26):

Here's a workaround from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If), i.e. use a type-dependent expression instead.

> Note: the discarded statement can't be ill-formed for every possible specialization:
>
> The common workaround for such a catch-all statement is a type-dependent expression that is always false:

e.g.

```
template<class T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};
```

then

```
static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value);
```

Comment: Ironic really since that's exactly what this gives us! Silly language.

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) illustrates a different variant: `template<class> inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;`

Answer (score 4):

taking a slightly different tack...

```
#include <ciso646>

template<auto x> void something();

template<class...Conditions>
constexpr int which(Conditions... cond)
{
    int sel = 0;
    bool found = false;
    auto elect = [&found, &sel](auto cond)
    {
        if (not found)
        {
            if (cond)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ++sel;
            }
        }
    };

    (elect(cond), ...);
    if (not found) throw "you have a logic error";
    return sel;
}

template<bool condition1, bool condition2, bool condition3>
void foo()
{
    auto constexpr sel = which(condition1, condition2, condition3);
    switch(sel)
    {
        case 0:
            something<1>();
            break;
        case 1:
            something<2>();
            break;
        case 2:
            something<3>();
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo<false, true, false>();
//    foo<false, false, false>(); // fails to compile
}
```

As I understand it, `which` is evaluated in constexpr context, which means that it is legal unless the program has to follow a code path that is illegal in a constexpr context.

For all expected cases, the `throw` path is not taken, so the function is legal. When illegal inputs are provided, we go down the ill-formed path, which causes a compiler error.

I'd be interested to know whether this solution is strictly correct from a language-lawyer perspective.

It works on gcc, clang and MSVC.

...or for fans of obfuscated code...

```
template<class...Conditions>
constexpr int which(Conditions... cond)
{
    auto sel = 0;
    ((cond or (++sel, false)) or ...) or (throw "program is ill-formed", false);
    return sel;
}
```