# C++17 make function return type template, then write implementation for supported types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I would like to convert the following example code

```
class Example{
public:
    float getFloat(){return 0;}
    int getInt(){return 0;};
    std::vector<float> getFloatVector(){
        return std::vector<float>();
    }
};
```

Into code with slightly better syntax - e.g. it should look like that:

```
class Example2 {
    public:
        template <class T> virtual T get();
    };
    Example2::get<float>(){
        return 0;
    }
    Example2::get<int>(){
        return 0;
    }
    Example2::get<std::vector<float>>(){
        return std::vector<float>();
    }
```

Of course the second example code does not compile but It shows how I would like to use Example class:

```
Example2 example;
LOGD("%d",example.get<float>());
```

Answer (score 2):

Member function template can't be declared as `virtual`, so you can change the declaration of primary template to

```
class Example2 {
public:
    template <class T> T get();
};
```

then specialize it like

```
template <>
float Example2::get<float>(){
    return 0;
}
template <>
int Example2::get<int>(){
    return 0;
}
template <>
std::vector<float> Example2::get<std::vector<float>>(){
    return std::vector<float>();
}
```

Since C++17 we can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) like

```
class Example2 {
public:
    template <class T> T get();
};

template <typename T>
T Example2::get() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) 
        return 0;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) 
        return 0;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<float>>) 
        return std::vector<float>();
    else
        return ...;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to throw a compilation error when using constexpr and if else ?
e.g. instead "return ...;" "throw a DO NOT COMPILE" error ?

Comment: @ConstantinGeier Yes. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/czTnHUdRFpqrABik)

Comment: Thanks. I also found songyuanyao's answer to exact this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945490/how-to-assert-that-a-constexpr-if-else-clause-never-happen