# if constexpr std::is_same under VS 2022

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, visual-studio-2022

I have converted one of my projects from VS 2019 to VS 2022 and the following conditional compilation template doesn't compile properly anymore:

```
struct T_USER;
struct T_SERVICE;

template<typename T>
class system_state
{
 public:
    system_state();
};


template<typename T>
system_state<T>::system_state()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, T_USER>)
    {
        std::cout << "User templ\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, T_SERVICE>)
    {
        std::cout << "Service templ\n";
    }
    else
    {
        //Bad type
        static_assert(false, "Bad template type in T: must be either T_USER or T_SERVICE");

        std::cout << "Unknown templ\n";
    }
}
```

The idea was to compile parts of code in `system_state` depending on a specific template, as such:

```
int main()
{
    system_state<T_USER> user_state;
}
```

But now the `if constexpr std::is_same` doesn't seem to detect my `T` and I'm always getting my `static_assert` clause:

> Bad template type in T: must be either T_USER or T_SERVICE

What has changed? It used to work in VS 2019.

Comment: I can't make it compile with any version of MSVC...  https://godbolt.org/z/dhs8r776q

Comment: Replacing `std::is_same` with `std::is_same_v` seems to fix it. Seems like a typo? https://godbolt.org/z/Gn9ezzz19

Comment: Yes, sorry. it was supposed to be `std::is_same_v`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945490/how-to-assert-that-a-constexpr-if-else-clause-never-happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is ill-formed because for [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if):

> Note: the discarded statement can't be ill-formed for every possible
> specialization:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> void f() {
>      if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
>          // ...
>      else
>        static_assert(false, "Must be arithmetic"); // ill-formed: invalid for every T
> }
> ```
>
> The common workaround for such a catch-all statement is a
> type-dependent expression that is always false:
>
> ```
> template<class> inline constexpr bool dependent_false_v = false;
> template <typename T>
> void f() {
>      if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
>          // ...
>      else
>        static_assert(dependent_false_v<T>, "Must be arithmetic"); // ok
> }
> ```

You can use the *type-dependent expression* above in the `else` branch too, e.g.

```
//Bad type
static_assert(dependent_false_v<T>, "Bad template type in T: must be either T_USER or T_SERVICE");
```

BTW: In `if constexpr (std::is_same<T, T_USER>)`, `std::is_same<T, T_USER>` is type but not a `bool` value; you should change it to `std::is_same_v<T, T_USER>`, or `std::is_same<T, T_USER>::value`, or `std::is_same<T, T_USER>()` (`std::is_same<T, T_USER>{}`).

Comment: Thanks. But what is `dependent_false_v`?

Comment: @c00000fd You can define it own as `template<class> inline constexpr bool dependent_false_v = false;`.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. Can you explain what exactly does that dependent_false_v do and why did it use to work under VS 2019?

Comment: @c00000fd You have to make the condition for `static_assert` depending on template parameter `T`; you can't use `false` directly. I'm not sure about VS2019, it might be a bug fixed from VS2022.

Comment: @songyuanyao  It is a conformance improvement: implemented in VS 2022 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/cpp-conformance-improvements?view=msvc-170  It says This change is a source breaking change. It applies in any mode that implies /Zc:permissive- or /Zc:static_assert. This change in behavior can be disabled by using the /Zc:static_assert- compiler option.