# Template function that matches only certain types?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I want to define a function template:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T arg)
```

But I want `T` to match only certain types. Specifically, `T` should derive (maybe through multiple inheritance) form a certain base class. Otherwise this template shouldn't be included in the overload set.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related to [How to I restrict a template class to certain types?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16976720/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Note that it is not a duplicate. I want to restrict a *function* template, while the linked question refers to a *class* template.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Would you not have closed it if this was an exact duplicate and you did have an answer on the other one?

Comment: @Barry I don't think it is an exact duplicate ... as an aside I mentioned the only reason I would not use the dup hammer is if I had an answer on the proposed dup.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Why not? Don't want to feel like you're gaming the system?

Comment: @Barry this [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277126/1708801) made me a lot more conservative about how I use it.

Comment: The key issue to select the best answer is: if someone tries to use your function with inappropriate T, do you want failure, or do you want other overloads to be considered?

Comment: @NirFriedman I don't want failure, I want other overloads to be considered. Should I edit the question?

Comment: @becko I think so, it will make your question more useful to future readers. If this is what you want, then you definitely want SFINAE as Barry's answer explains; static_assert will not serve your needs. If you are ok with failure, then static_assert is simpler and gives better error messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use SFINAE with [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value
          >>
void foo(T arg);
```

That will only include `foo` in the overload set if `T` inherits from `Foo`. Note that this includes ambiguous and inaccessible bases as well. If you want a solution that only allows for `T`s that inherit *publicly* and *unambiguously* from `Foo`, then you can instead use [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible):

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              std::is_convertible<T*, Foo*>::value
          >>
void foo(T arg);
```

Note the reversal of arguments.

Regardless of which form you pick, it can be aliased for brevity:

```
template <typename T>
using enable_if_foo = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value>;

template <typename T,
          typename = enable_if_foo<T>>
void foo(T arg);
```

---

This works because [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) has a nested type named `type` if and only if the boolean passed in is `true`. So if `std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value` is `true`, `enable_if_t` gets instantiated to `void`, as if we had written:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = void>
void foo(T arg);
```

But, if `T` does not inherit from `Foo`, then the type trait will evaluate as `false`, and `std::enable_if_t<false>` is a substitution failure - there is no `typename enable_if<false>::type`. You might expect this to a compile error, but **s**ubstitution **f**ailure **i**s **n**ot **a**n **e**rror (sfinae). It's just a template deduction failure. So the effect is that `foo<T>` is simply removed from the set of viable overload candidates in this case, no different from any other template deduction failure.

Comment: I don't find `std::enable_if_t`. Should it be `std::enable_if`?

Comment: `template<bool b, class T=void>using enable_if_t=typename std::enable_if<b,T>::type;` is a one-line implementation of `enable_if_t`.  Stick it in `namespace notstd`, and when your compiler updates, switch `notstd::enable_if_t` to `std::enable_if_t`.  The alias is well worth the extra bit of boilerplate, the syntax of `enable_if` without it is annoying.

Comment: This is what I want, thanks (+1). Do you mind explaining, at least on the surface, how this works?

Comment: @Yakk Also, I will be writing a lot of functions like `foo`, and all should match only if `T` inherits from the same base class. Is there a shorthand I can use, a `typedef` or something, to avoid spelling the whole `template<typename T, ... enable_if_t ...` everytime?

Answer (score 5):

SFINAE based techniques such as the following;

```
template <typename T,
  typename Test = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value>>
void foo(T arg);
```

Are good to remove the function from the overload list - which would be a general case.

If you wish to keep the function in the list, and if chosen as the best overload to fail if the type matches some criteria (such as a base requirement here), the `static_assert` can be used;

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T arg)
{
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value, "failed type check");
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++1z with concepts lite, you can do this:

```
template<class T>
requires std::is_base_of<Foo, T>{}()
void foo(T arg) {
}
```

under the current (experimental) implementation.  Which is pretty clean and clear.  There **may** be a way to do something like:

```
template<derived_from<Foo> T>
void foo(T arg) {
}
```

but I haven't worked it out.  You can definitely do:

```
template<derived_from_foo T>
void foo(T arg){
}
```

where we have a custom concept called `derived_from_foo` that applies iff the type is derived from `foo`.  What I don't know how to do is template concepts -- concepts generated from template type parameters.

---

In C++14, here are two methods.  First, normal SFINAE:

```
template<class T,
  class=std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>{}>
>
void foo(T arg) {
}
```

here we create a template that deduces the type `T` from its argument.  It then tries to deduce its **second** type argument from the first argument.

The second type argument has no name (hence `class=`), because we are only using it for a SFINAE test.

The test is `enable_if_t< condition >`.  `enable_if_t< condition >` generates the type `void` if `condition` is true.  If `condition` is false, it fails in "the immediate context", generating a substitution failure.

SFINAE is "Substitution failure is not an error" -- if your type `T` generates a failure in the "immediate context" of the function template signature, this doesn't generate a compile-time error, but instead results in the function template not being considered a valid overload in this case.

"Immediate context" is a technical term here, but basically it means the error has to be "early enough" to be caught.  If it requires compiling bodies of functions to find the error, that is not in "the immediate context".

Now, this isn't the only way.  I personally like hiding my SFINAE code behind a gloss of respectability.  Below, I use tag dispatching to "hide" the failure somewhere else, instead of putting it right up front in the function signature:

```
template<class T>
struct tag {
  using type=T;
  constexpr tag(tag const&) = default;
  constexpr tag() = default;
  template<class U,
    class=std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T,U>{}>
  >
  constexpr tag(tag<U>) {}
};

struct Base{};
struct Derived:Base{};

template<class T>
void foo( T t, tag<Base> = tag<T>{} ) {
}
```

here we create a `tag` dispatch type, and it allows conversion to base.  `tag` lets us worth with types *as values*, and use more normal C++ operations on them (instead of template-like metaprogramming `<>`s all over the place).

We then give `foo` a second argument of type `tag<Base>`, then construct it with a `tag<T>`.  This fails to compile if `T` is not a derived type from `Base`.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3597371c467ccced).

The nice thing about this solution is that the code that makes it not work seems more intuitive -- `tag<Unrelated>` cannot convert to `tag<Base>`.  This does not, however, prevent the function from being considered for overload resolution, which can be a problem.

A way with less boiler plate is:

```
template<class T>
void foo( T t, Base*=(T*)0 ) {
}
```

where we use the fact that pointers can be converted iff there is a derivation relationship between them.

---

In C++11 (and without `constexpr` support), we first write a helper:

```
namespace notstd {
  template<bool b, class T=void>
  using enable_if_t=typename std::enable_if<b,T>::type;
}
```

then:

```
template<class T,
  class=notstd::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value>
>
void foo(T arg) {
}
```

if you don't like the helper, we get this ugly extra:

```
template<class T,
  class=typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value>::type
>
void foo(T arg) {
}
```

the second C++14 technique above can also be translated to C++11.

---

You can write an alias that does the test if you want:

```
template<class U>
using base_test=notstd::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, U>::value>;

template<class T,
  class=base_test<T>
>
void foo(T arg) {
}
```

Comment: +1 Great answer, but please see my last comment to Barry's answer. Is there a shorthand to avoid writing the same template many times? I am using CLion and I think it doesn't fully understand C++14, so I am stuck with C++11.

Comment: @becko short-form alias added.  Note however that the `tag` solution is pretty brief.

Comment: "gloss of respectability", *snort*. your [excellent as usual] answers always crack me up.