# Function overloading using template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading

Here are two overloading declarations of a function:

```
void fun(char& arg);
void fun(int&  arg);
void fun(long& arg);
```

The definitions are doing the same job:

```
void fun(char& arg) { ++arg; }
void fun(int&  arg) { ++arg; }
void fun(long& arg) { ++arg; }
```

How to declare and define the function once by using template, which accepts only `int`, `char` and `long` types for the argument? Error should appear as soon as possible (before runtime) if the function is misused (e.g. a variable of `double` type is passed).

Comment: `s/two/three/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ templates that accept only certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types)

Comment: This may also qualify as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31596613/2602718

Answer (score 4):

You can just `static_assert` in the body of the function with a bunch of `std::is_same`

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T& arg) 
{ 
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<T, char> || 
        std::is_same_v<T, int> || 
        std::is_same_v<T, long>, 
        "bad call"); 
    ++arg; 
}
```

Comment: I think I like this solution the best as you can actually provide a nice, readable error message, instead of the compilers very verbose error message.

Comment: I like how I gave the same solution, at the exact same moment, but got -4 and no upvotes or edits because of a tangential, admittedly wrong statement :P Oh well, guess that's the way the cookie crumbles.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) with [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int> || 
                 std::is_same_v<T, char> || 
                 std::is_same_v<T, long>> 
fun(T& arg) { ++arg; }
```

For other types you'll get a [*no matching function for call*](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PBAC0HVsqcBFVuKj) error.

Comment: This has the benefit that you can provide different overloads of `fun` for types other than `char&`, `int&` and `long&` elsewhere

Comment: With return value: `template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, char> || std::is_same_v<T, long>>* = nullptr> T fun(const T& arg) { return arg+1; }`

Comment: @Andy You can also `template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, char> || std::is_same_v<T, long>, T> fun...`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++20, it can be implemented with [constraints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```
template <class T>
concept IsIntegral = is_same_v<T, char> 
                  || is_same_v<T,  int> 
                  || is_same_v<T, long>;

template <IsIntegral T>
void foo(T& arg) { ++arg; }

template <class T> requires IsIntegral<T>
void bar(T& arg) { ++arg; }
```