# How to get C++-template-like behavior but only allow two specific types to be instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to get a specific type of behavior from an inline C++ function, and I'm not sure if there's a way to do it or not.

I want my function to accept either a signed or an unsigned 16-bit value as an argument, perform an operation on that value, and then return a value of that same type.  If the argument's signed/unsigned-ness is ambiguous (e.g. because it's a constant), then it's okay for the compiler to just pick the signed version.  Here's a toy program showing my first attempt at getting that behavior:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdint>

  int16_t getValuePlusOne( int16_t x) {return x+1;}
 uint16_t getValuePlusOne(uint16_t x) {return x+1;}

 using namespace std;

 int main(int, char **)
 {
     int16_t   signedVal = -15;
    uint16_t unsignedVal = 23;

    cout << getValuePlusOne(  signedVal) << endl;  // works, yay!
    cout << getValuePlusOne(unsignedVal) << endl;  // works, yay!
    cout << getValuePlusOne(1234)        << endl;  // COMPILE ERROR, ambiguous!  D'oh!
    return 0;
 }
```

So that almost worked, but it errors out on the getValuePlusOne(1234) since 1234 is ambiguous (it could be signed or unsigned).  Fair enough, but I'd like it not to do that.

So here's my second attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T> T getValuePlusOne(T val) {return val+1;}

using namespace std;

int main(int, char **)
{
    int16_t   signedVal = 5;
   uint16_t unsignedVal = 5;

   cout << getValuePlusOne(  signedVal) << endl;  // works, yay!
   cout << getValuePlusOne(unsignedVal) << endl;  // works, yay!
   cout << getValuePlusOne(1234)        << endl;  // works, yay!

   uint32_t inappropriateType32 = 54321;
   cout << getValuePlusOne(inappropriateType32) << endl;  // works, but I want this to be a compile-time error!  D'oh!

   float inappropriateTypeFloat = 666.0;
   cout << getValuePlusOne(inappropriateTypeFloat) << endl;  // works, but I want this to be a compile-time error!

   return 0;
}
```

This version works just how I want it to work for the first three calls to getValuePlusOne() -- they compile without errors and the template mechanism makes sure that getValuePlusOne()'s return type matches its argument type, and chooses a default argument/return type in the ambiguous case.  Yay!

But -- this version also allows the user to pass in inappropriate values (e.g. 32-bit integers, or even -- gasp -- floating point types) which don't make sense in the context of my application, so I want the compiler to flag those calls as compile-time errors, and that doesn't happen with this implementation.

Is there any way for me to have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976720/how-do-i-restrict-a-template-class-to-certain-built-in-types

Comment: Note that `1234` is of type `int`. If you want `getValuePlusOne(1234)` to work, then `int x = 1234; getValuePlusOne(x);` would work, too.

Comment: You can set a function template to `= delete;` to disable calls from any types you haven't explicitly enabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
template <typename T> T getValuePlusOne(T val)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int16_t>::value || std::is_same<T, uint16_t>::value, "Incorrect type");
    return val+1;
}
```

Still, `getValuePlusOne(1234)` fails. But it's not because the type is ambiguous. It's because `T` is `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sfinae to limit the function to parameters that conform to certain criteria:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_any_int16 = std::is_same<T, int16_t>::value || std::is_same<T, uint16_t>::value;

template<typename T>
auto getValuePlusOne(T x) -> std::enable_if_t<is_any_int16<T>, T> {
    return x + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to make a templated function and split it into header and cpp file. This way you have to provide the allowed types, otherwise you'll get a compilation error:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GetValuePlusOne.h"

int main() {
    int i = 2;
    std::cout << GetValuePlusOne(i) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

GetValuePlusOne.h:

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
T GetValuePlusOne(T value);
```

GetValuePlusOne.cpp:

```
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
T GetValuePlusOne(T value) {
    return value + 1;
}

template int GetValuePlusOne<int>(int);
template int16_t  GetValuePlusOne<int16_t>(int16_t );
template uint16_t   GetValuePlusOne<uint16_t >(uint16_t  );
```

As Igor already pointed out you need an "int" template to compile your "1234" example. Hope this works, couldn't test it.