# cast list<A*> to list<B*> where B inherits A

Tags: c++, templates, stl, casting, containers

I got a function

```
void doSomething(list<A*> list1, list<A*> list2)
```

And classes

```
class B : A  
class C : A
```

Is there a direct way to call my function like

```
void doSomething(list<B*> listOfB, list<C*> listOfC)
```

or do I have to wrap it manually like

```
void doSomething(list<B*> listOfB, list<C*> listOfC) {
  list<A*> l1;
  list<A*> l2;

  for (B* b : listOfB)
    l1.insert(b);

  for (C* c : listOfC)
    l2.insert(c);

  doSomething(l1, l2); //calling the function taking supertype
}
```

I tried unsuccessfully to cast `list<B*>` to `list<A*>`, my guess is that due to template specialization, the compiler consider `list<B*>` and `list<A*>` unrelated, however B inherits A.

Can someone confirm this, or come with a different way to manage this problem ?

Comment: That is right. They are different types and there is no mechanism to cast between them.

Comment: you should declare the list as `list<A*>` which u will pass as parameter, whether you populate it with `B*` or `C*`. For polymorphic type, always use base pointer/reference regardless of the actual type.

Comment: Call me crazy, but I'd just make this a function template.

Comment: Rewrite your algorithms so they work in terms of iterators, not containers?

Comment: You could constructor those temporary lists via iterator-constructor, but personally I would lean more toward revamping `doSomething` to just take four iteratoro params. If B and C inherit from A, then `(*it)->Asomething()` , where `Asomething` is a member of `A` (and thus `B` and `C`) would probably be a reasonable solution.

Comment: If you want a quick solution and you feel like living dangerously you could try a `reinterpret_cast`. I think I saw it used before on containers of related objects ... But you should consider safer alternatives though.

Comment: `list<B*>` is not a `list<A*>` because it misses `.push_back(A*)`. IS-A requires that the derived class supports all methods of the base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition (and juanchopanza's comment) is correct - the lists are completely unrelated types.

The options are:

1. use `list<A*>` everywhere in the first place, even when you know the dynamic type is `B*` or `C*`
2. write a wrapper over `list<A*>` which casts to/from the correct dynamic type - this is equivalent to the (un)boxing behaviour in Java generics
3. re-write `doSomething` as a function template whose only constraint is that the types be convertible

   ```
   template <typename Sequence1, typename Sequence2>
   void doSomething(Sequence1 &x, Sequence2 &y) {
     // require only that *x.begin() is convertible with *y.begin(), etc.
   }
   ```

   I'd also agree with Kerrek's suggestion that this should use iterators instead, but that doesn't change the type requirement significantly - you just get two iterator type params instead of two container type params

Comment: Thanks to all for your quick answer, definitely useful.
I think I'm gonna go for a function template, and look upon how to restrict the template type to a subclass of A.

Comment: You should be able to use `std::is_base_of` with either `enable_if` or `static_assert`. It's often useful to permit duck-typing though, even though the error messages aren't as good.

Comment: yes, I checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175219/restrict-c-template-parameter-to-subclass) about it, thanks for it @Useless :)